# Does not exist on type 'false | HTMLAudioElement'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

In React (Next.js) with hooks using typescript, I want to create a reference to Audio. The error I'm getting is:-

```
Property 'duration' does not exist on type 'false | HTMLAudioElement'.
  Property 'duration' does not exist on type 'false'.ts(2339)
```

```
const audioRef = useRef(typeof Audio !== 'undefined' && new Audio(mp3Src));
  const { duration } = audioRef.current.duration;
```

I've also tried like this

```
  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(mp3Src));
  const { duration } = audioRef.current;
```

which then throws an error in the browser

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: Audio is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

Complete code

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';

interface Props {
  imgSrc: string;
  mp3Src: string;
}

const AudioPlayer: NextPage<Props> = ({ imgSrc, mp3Src }) => {
  // const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(mp3Src));
  const audioRef = useRef(typeof Audio !== 'undefined' && new Audio(mp3Src));

  // const duration = audioRef.current.duration;
  const { duration } = audioRef.current;

  const intervalRef = useRef<any>();
  const [trackProgress, setTrackProgress] = useState<number>(0);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const play = (): void => {
    audioRef.current.play();
    startTimer();
    setIsPlaying(true);
  };

  const pause = (): void => {
    audioRef.current.pause();
    setIsPlaying(false);
  };

  const startTimer = (): void => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTrackProgress(audioRef.current.currentTime);
    }, 100);
  };

  const onScrub = (value: number): void => {
    // Clear any timers already running
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    audioRef.current.currentTime = value;
    setTrackProgress(audioRef.current.currentTime);
  };

  const onScrubEnd = (): void => {
    if (!isPlaying) {
      setIsPlaying(true);
    }
    startTimer();
  };
  const mute = (): void => {
    audioRef.current.volume = 0;
  };
  return (
    <div className='AudioPlayer'>
      <Image alt='menu' src={imgSrc} width='30' height='20' />
      <div onClick={play}>Play</div>
      <div onClick={pause}>Pause</div>
      <div>{trackProgress}</div>
      <div>{isPlaying}</div>
      <input
        type='range'
        value={trackProgress}
        step='1'
        min='0'
        max={duration ? duration : `${duration}`}
        className='progress'
        onChange={(e): void => onScrub(+e.target.value)}
        onMouseUp={onScrubEnd}
        onKeyUp={onScrubEnd}
      />
      <div onClick={mute}>Mute</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

Comment: What do you want to do if `audioRef.current` is false? Or equivalently, what do you want to do if `Audio` is undefined?

Comment: if `audioRef.current` is false, I could log that the source is invalid and if `Audio` is undefined I could log that the browser does not support audio

Comment: K, then you just need to check for that case in your code. See Saravana's answer for an example of checking whether audioRef.current is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NextJS uses Node to render anything in the server that allows you to build static and server side rendered apps. Therefore, any browser's APIs such as `window` or in your case `Audio`, do not exist in Node.

When Next tries to run the following code on node, and since `Audio` does not exist. It will evaluate to `false` since `typeof Audio` is `undefined`.

```
const audioRef = useRef(typeof Audio !== 'undefined' && new Audio(mp3Src));
```

To ensure the code is run only on browsers (not Node), you can use the `useEffect` hook.

e.g.

```
const AudioPlayer: NextPage<Props> = ({ imgSrc, mp3Src }) => {
  // const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(mp3Src));
  const [audioElem, setAudioElem] = useState<HTMLAudioElement>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof Audio !== 'undefined' && mp3Src) {
      const audio = new Audio(mp3Src);
      setAudioElem(audio);
    }
  }, [mp3Src])
  

  // const duration = audioRef.current.duration;
  const { duration } = audioElem || {};

...
```

Some helpful links;

- https://dev.to/vvo/how-to-solve-window-is-not-defined-errors-in-react-and-next-js-5f97
- https://frontend-digest.com/why-is-window-not-defined-in-nextjs-44daf7b4604e

Comment: that got it, thank you